# Контрол для ввода цифр

Tags: wpf

Подскажите, как называется Контрол, который имеет справа стрелки вверх и вниз.
По нажатию на стрелки он делает инкремент или декремент значения.

В WinForms точно такой был, да название забыл. Есть ли аналог в WPF?

Comment: Вроде там есть элемент SpinEdit, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Данный вопрос уже обсуждался на сайте. Прочитай вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841293/where-is-the-wpf-numeric-updown-control

Comment: Есть, но не в штатном наборе, установите [Extended.Wpf.Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/)